# write:errno=0 when using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Basically, I need to submit the password on the port 30001 (where host is localhost) using SSL. So I tried this:

```
echo [then there is the password to submit] | openssl s_client -quiet -connect localhost:30001
```

And the output I get is:

```
write:errno=0
```

Any ideas on what it is and how to fix it? (I'm new to this, so I don't know much)

UPDATE -
Ok, so it worked, when I added -debug. I don’t have enough reputation to post pictures tho

Comment: Can you please run the `openssl` command with `-debug` and show what exactly are you echoing, you can replace the actual password with something else. And just to verify if the endpoint is listening, can you also show if it responds to a TLS handshake using curl or openssl, whatever you wish to use.

Comment: @pikaynu ok. I’ll add the picture to my question

Comment: @pikaynu when I added -debug to openssl, it started to work properly. Thank you :) can you explain why tho? I’ll add the picture to the question

Comment: @pikaynu Ooops, I don’t have enough reputation to post pictures, but if you ask, I can type in here some things I got there

Comment: The `-debug` flag is to just show what openssl is seeing. It shouldn't have affected how it works. There should be a different reason for it to not work or work.

Comment: Ok, but for some reason it doesn’t show error when I use -debug. Thank you :)